# MediaWiki API - How to retrieve the maximum number of pages inside a Category?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Using the media wiki API, I need to get all pages
inside a Category, so I set the parameter **cmlimit** 
to **max**, but as stated in the documentation, this
bill wring just 500 results.

This is my query:

```
http://lost.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Characters&cmlimit=max&format=json
```

How can I make that query to get all pages inside the category? I barely understand the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, at least not using a single query.

What you need to do is to take the value in the `query-continue` field and add that to the query to get another page of results. And then repeat that until the response has no `query-continue`, which indicates that it's the last page.

In your case, the query for the second (and final) page would be:

http://lost.wikia.com/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Characters&cmlimit=max&format=json&cmcontinue=page|4d4159484557|9538

Answer (score 0):

The original accepted answer is now a bit outdated, and the `query-continue` field has been deprecated to [Raw continue query](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Raw_query_continue).

These days, retrieving all results from a query is done by using loops to perform multiple API calls anytime the `continue` element is present in the API results. (You keep looping until the `continue` element stops appearing in the results.) There is now [a nice Mediawiki article](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Continue) explaining how this new continuing feature works in more depth.